# Chopping of digits (after the dot) in C++

Tags: c++

i need to "chop off" a 'double' so that he'll have 3 digits after the dot (not rounding, just cut everything else off).

Here is my code:

```
double multiply_by = (pow(10.0, _digits_percision));
_number = (_number * multiply_by);
_number = (int) _number;
_number = (_number / multiply_by);
```

When i'm inputing 1.001, my output (after performing this code) is 1.
When my input is 1.007, my output is 1.006.
It happens only with 1.xxx
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: instead of converting the double into an integer, what happens if you run `floor(_number)` instead?

Comment: Same thing will happen. It is a function of how floating point numbers are represented in computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer is using a base 2 floating point representation. When you input 1.007, the computer converts this to the closest possible representation. It cannot represent 1.007 exactly. The representation is instead something like 1.0069999999999999. Multiply by 1000 and you get 1006.9999999999999. Converting to an int yields 1006.

BTW, this isn't going to happen just with numbers of the form 1.xxx. You just haven't tried enough cases.

**Addendum**
We had a very similar question today. Rather than repeating my answer here, take a look at my answer to [Returning double with precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373205/returning-double-with-precision/7373720#7373720) .

Comment: Actually, the closest double value to 1.007 is 1.0069999999999998951949464753852225840091705322265625 :)

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading about [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). If you want to truncate a number to N *decimal* points and store it in a *binary* form, you are likely to get errors for some inputs.