# Returning double with precision

Tags: c++, c, double

Say I have a method returning a `double`, but I want to determine the precision after the dot of the value to be returned. I don't know the value of the `double` varaible.

Example:

```
double i = 3.365737;
return i;
```

I want the return value to be with precision of 3 number after the dot

Meaning: the return value is `3.365`.

Another example:

```
double i = 4644.322345;
return i;
```

I want the return value to be: `4644.322`

Comment: Normally you would just format output to 3 decimal places. Much easier that way.

Comment: There is no `double` for 3.365. There is only `3.3650000000000002`, so that's what you'll get, at best. Listen to the answers that suggest to limit the number of decimal places only when printing.

Comment: @ltzik984: what's the desired behavior for negative numbers?

Comment: @Matteo Italia same as positive numbers...

Comment: @ltzik984: i.e. just throw away the extra digits (round-towards-zero)?

Comment: @Pascal: `3.365` is actually 3.3650000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is truncation of decimal digits after a certain digit. You can easily do that with the `floor` function from `<math.h>` (or `std::floor` from `<cmath>` if you're using C++):

```
double TruncateNumber(double In, unsigned int Digits)
{
    double f=pow(10, Digits);
    return ((int)(In*f))/f;
}
```

Still, I think that in some cases you may get some strange results (the last digit being one over/off) due to how floating point internally works.

---

On the other hand, most of time you just pass around the `double` as is and truncate it only when outputting it on a stream, which is done automatically with the right stream flags.

Comment: Floor will do the wrong thing for negative numbers. If the OP really wants to truncate those extra digits you need round-toward-zero: In other words, cast to int.

Comment: @David: correct if he wants truncation, the problem is that he only presented two examples, none of which deals with negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to take care with the borderline cases. Any implementation based solely on `pow` and casting or `fmod` will occasionally give wrong results, particularly so an implementation based on `pow(- PRECISION)`.

The safest bet is to implement something that neither C nor C++ provide: A fixed point arithmetic capability. Lacking that, you will need to find the representations of the pertinent borderline cases. This question is similar to the question on how Excel does rounding. Adapting my answer there, [How does Excel successfully Rounds Floating numbers even though they are imprecise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930786/how-does-excel-successfully-rounds-floating-numbers-even-though-they-are-imprecis/7211688#7211688) , to this problem,

```
// Compute 10 to some positive integral power.
// Dealing with overflow (exponent > 308) is an exercise left to the reader.
double pow10 (unsigned int exponent) {
  double result = 1.0;
  double base = 10.0;
  while (exponent > 0) {
    if ((exponent & 1) != 0) result *= base;
    exponent >>= 1;
    base *= base;
  }
  return result;
}

// Truncate number to some precision.
// Dealing with nonsense such as nplaces=400 is an exercise left to the reader.
double truncate (double x, int nplaces) {
  bool is_neg = false;

  // Things will be easier if we only have to deal with positive numbers.
  if (x < 0.0) {
     is_neg = true;
     x = -x;
  }

  // Construct the supposedly truncated value (round down) and the nearest
  // truncated value above it.
  double round_down, round_up;
  if (nplaces < 0) {
    double scale = pow10 (-nplaces);
    round_down   = std::floor (x / scale);
    round_up     = (round_down + 1.0) * scale;
    round_down  *= scale;
  }
  else {
    double scale = pow10 (nplaces);
    round_down   = std::floor (x * scale);
    round_up     = (round_down + 1.0) / scale;
    round_down  /= scale;
  }

  // Usually the round_down value is the desired value.
  // On rare occasions it is the rounded-up value that is.
  // This is one of those cases where you do want to compare doubles by ==.
  if (x != round_up) x = round_down;

  // Correct the sign if needed.
  if (is_neg) x = -x;

  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "remove" precision from a double.  You could have: 4644.322000.  It's a different number but the precision is the same.

As @David Heffernan said do it when you convert it to a string for display.

Answer (score 0):

You want to truncate your double to `n` decimal places, then you can use this function:

```
#import <cmath>

double truncate_to_places(double d, int n) {
    return d - fmod(d, pow(10.0, -n));
}
```

Comment: From his first example it seems that he wants truncation, not rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiplying and dividing by powers of 10 like the other answers, you can use the `fmod` function to find the digits after the precision you want, and then subtract to remove them.

```
#include <math.h>
#define PRECISION 0.001
double truncate(double x) {
    x -= fmod(x,PRECISION);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: `pow()` can be a very expensive function. You may like to make sure its is evaluated by the compiler. ;)

Comment: @Peter Good call. I assumed it would, but I just tested and it doesn't. I'll update my post to just use `0.001`.

Comment: -1. This gives the wrong answer for x=1.0, for example. It does a pretty lousy job on the borderline cases. Numbers input as `x.xxx` have a better than 50-50 chance of being truncated downward by 1/1000.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this with plain `double`s, but you can write a `class` or simply `struct` like

```
struct lim_prec_float {
  float value;
  int precision;
};
```

then have your function

```
lim_prec_float testfn() {
  double i = 3.365737;
  return lim_prec_float{i, 4};
}
```

(4 = 1 before point + 3 after. This uses a C++11 initialization list, it would be better if `lim_prec_float` was a `class` with proper constructors.)

When you now want to output the variable, do this with a custom

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &tgt, const lim_prec_float &v) {
  std::stringstream s;
  s << std::setprecision(v.precision) << v.value;
  return (tgt << s.str());
}
```

Now you can, for instance,

```
int main() {
  std::cout << testfn() << std::endl
            << lim_prec_float{4644.322345, 7} << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

which will output

```
3.366
4644.322
```

this is because `std::setprecision` means *rounding* to the desired number of places, which is likely what you really want. If you actually mean *truncate*, you can modify the `operator<<` with one of the truncation functions given by the other answers.

Comment: The suggested answer is not correct. Your function rounds the values (not truncating them). As you can see in the description, the desired result for 3.365737 is 3.365 (not 3.366).

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you format a date before displaying it, you should do the same with double.

However, here are two approaches I have used for rounding.

```
double roundTo3Places(double d) {
    return round(d * 1000) / 1000.0;
}

double roundTo3Places(double d) {
    return (long long) (d * 1000 + (d > 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5)) / 1000.0;
}
```

The later is faster, however numbers cannot be larger than 9e15